# SQL Group By a Partition By

Tags: sql-server, group-by, partition-by

This must be accomplished in MS SQL Server. I believe `OVER( PARTITION BY)` must be used, but I've failed at all my tries and I end up counting the records to each ID or something else...

I have this table:

```
| ID   | COLOR  |
+------+--------+
| 1    | Red    |
| 1    | Green  |
| 1    | Blue   |
| 2    | Red    |
| 2    | Green  |
| 2    | Blue   |
| 3    | Red    |
| 3    | Brown  |
| 3    | Orange |
```

Notice that ID = 1 and ID = 2 have precisely the same values for COLOR, however ID = 3 only shares the value COLOR = Red.

I would like to group the table as follows:

```
| COLOR  | COUNT | GROUPING |
+--------+-------+----------+
| Red    | 2     | Type 1   |
| Green  | 2     | Type 1   |
| Blue   | 2     | Type 1   |
| Red    | 1     | Type 2   |
| Brown  | 1     | Type 2   |
| Orange | 1     | Type 2   |
```

This would mean that ID = 1 and ID = 2 share the same 3 values for color and they are aggregated together as Type 1. Although ID = 3 shares one value for color to ID = 1 and ID = 2 (which is 'Red') the rest of the values are not shared, as such it is considered of Type 2 (different grouping).

The tables used are simple examples and are enough to replicate to the entire dateset, however each ID can have in theory hundreds of records with different values for colors in each row. However they are unique, one ID can't have the the same color in different rows.

My best attempt:

```
SELECT
    ID, 
    COLOR,
    CONCAT ('TYPE ', COUNT(8) OVER( PARTITION by ID)) AS COLOR_GROUP
FROM 
    {TABLE};
```

Result:

```
| ID   | COLOR  | GROUPING |
+------+--------+----------+
| 1    | Green  | Type 3   |
| 1    | Blue   | Type 3   |
| 1    | Red    | Type 3   |
| 2    | Green  | Type 3   |
| 2    | Blue   | Type 3   |
| 2    | Red    | Type 3   |
| 3    | Red    | Type 3   |
| 3    | Brown  | Type 3   |
| 3    | Orange | Type 3   |
```

Although the results are terrible I've tried different methods, none of them is better.

Hope I was clear enough.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Also please show us your failed attempt.

Comment: Done! My attempt is terrible, I know, and it really doesn't convey the testing and search I've done, but it is still the best result I could obtain that is interpretable and not complete gibberish.

Comment: Why is `RED` appearing twice? You want that in both the Types??

Comment: Yes, RED is actually the common factor but it doesn’t matter. Image that the records for each ID are read together like (RED, GREEN, BLUE) on ID = 1 compares to (RED, GREEN, BLUE) on ID = 2, since they match they get counted twice. When compared to (RED, BROWN, ORANGE) on ID = 3 they don’t match and so ID = 3 is aggregated in a different Type and counts only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

```
declare @t table ( ID  int,COLOR varchar(100))
insert into @t select 1   ,'Red'    
insert into @t select 1   ,'Green'  
insert into @t select 1   ,'Blue'   
insert into @t select 2   ,'Red'    
insert into @t select 2   ,'Green'  
insert into @t select 2   ,'Blue'   
insert into @t select 3   ,'Red'    
insert into @t select 3   ,'Brown'  
insert into @t select 3   ,'Orange'


select *, STUFF((SELECT CHAR(10) + ' '+COLOR
                  FROM @t t_in where t_in.ID=t.ID
                  order by COLOR
                   FOR XML PATH ('')) , 1, 1, '') COLOR_Combined 
into #temp
from @t t

select COLOR, count(color) [COUNT], 'TYPE ' + convert(varchar(10), dense_rank() OVER (order by [grouping])) [GROUPING]
from
(   
    select id, COLOR, COLOR_Combined,  (row_number() over (order by id) - row_number() over (partition by Color_Combined order by id)) [grouping]
    from #temp
)t
group by COLOR, [grouping]
drop table if exists #temp
```

Please find the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cc0695a2fe547712d4bed1df58949433)**.

Comment: Amazing! From what I could gather from the fiddle it is precisely what I wanted. I will test it out later today to see the replication to my entire dataset. Thank you.

Comment: Tested and working as intended. Minor adjustments to apply to the dataset, bu overall an excellent solution. Thank you!